# Best way to store 1000's of MapKit annotations + show annotations in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mapkit, geojson

Question: What is the best way to store 1000s of `MapKit` annotations, which will be displayed on a map and should also be browseable in a `tableView`? The user should also be able to mark selected annotations as favorites and have them shown in a separate `tableView`.

Background: I'm learning iOS programming (through Udemy, Google and Stack Overflow). I'm currently trying to make a `MapKit`-based app that shows a number of annotations on a map. Each annotation represents a particular type of location. For testing purposes, I've made a dummy GeoJSON file (located in the app, not on a server), which stores each location, like so:

```
 {
        "type" : "Feature",
        "properties" : {
            "location" : "Norway",
            "title" : "Annotation Title",
            "website" : "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
        },
        "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [10, 60]
        }
    },
```

This works fine; my dummy objects are parsed and put on the map just fine. But eventually, I will have 1000s of real annotations, not just my handful of dummy annotations.

[Map View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNehJ.jpg)

Here's where my skills are insufficient: I want the user to be able to mark a particular location as a favorite, which of course should persist through app updates, iOS updates and ideally between the user's multiple devices.

[Favorites view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piPNV.jpg)

The user should also be able to browse all annotations, sorted by country and then state.

[Browse view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6uHS.jpg)

What is a good way to approach this? I tried to break it down into:

1. Find a good way to store the annotations -- GeoJSON maybe not ideal, given points 2 and (particularly) 3? Should I look into a database setup?
2. Populate a `tableView` with all the annotations in the database, with the first `tableView` showing all countries, and tapping a row segueing into another `tableView` with all states in that country, and another segue into a third `tableView` with every annotation in that state.
3. Letting the user mark selected annotations as favorites, and populating a new `tableView` with only those that are marked as favorite.

Comment: Well, MapKit is very, very fast when dealing with annotations. I have a project with several ten thousands of annotations without a problem. So there might be no problem in that direction. Storing all that annotations, well there are some possibilities and the easiest way to get it up and working should be to use "userDefaults" (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults). This would not be a very elegant way, but it will work and you can go further with your development to find out what are the key requirements for your app. After that  you work on a storage strategy.

Comment: For the tableViews: in ViewDidLoad() get the data you want to display in a local dataStructure. You also should read about the different architecture models. A good read is this article: https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/the-perfect-ios-app-architecture-4e3d1ab96fa4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer the question I would like to point out that displaying 1000s of `MKAnnotationView` on a map is a whole problem itself too and you would want to look into using the `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:` method or `MKClusterAnnotation` for these annotations to avoid screen lag.

Now to answer what you actually asked, rather than thinking about how to store data for one feature in your app. Think more about how the data should be stored for the entire app its self.

https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/ios-development/data-persistence-ios-swift - This link discusses various options for persistent data storage and their advantages/disadvantages. As you said you are currently learning iOS courses **I would suggest CoreData** as it is a native IOS-specific framework that would be a good addition to your learning and will likely be covered by Udemy. Another reason is that CoreData is easy to set up and learn with lots of documentation from Apple so should be a good start for a "newby".

**CoreData Example**

Create your Model

[image]

Create a CoreData manager

```
class CoreDataManager {
static let shared = CoreDataManager()
private init() {}
private lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "PillReminder")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { _, error in
        _ = error.map { fatalError("Unresolved error \($0)") }
    })
    return container
}()

var mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return persistentContainer.viewContext
}

func backgroundContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    return persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
}
```

Loading an Array of Pills

```
func loadPills() -> [Pill] {
let mainContext = CoreDataManager.shared.mainContext
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Pill> = Pill.fetchRequest()
do {
    let results = try mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    return results
}
catch {
    debugPrint(error)
}
```

Save a new Pill entity

```
func savePill(name: String) throws {
let context = CoreDataManager.shared.backgroundContext()
context.perform {
    let entity = Pill.entity()
    let pill = Pill(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    pill.name = name
    pill.amount = 2
    pill.dozePerDay = 1
    pill.lastUpdate = Date()
    try context.save()
}
```

}